# How to Invoke class which is same as String

Tags: java, automation, frameworks

I have implemented the Keyword Driven Automation Framework. I defined all my Keywords in the form of function / method ( each keyword as a method, and i have 100 + Keywords i.e methods).

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");
Method  method = c.getDeclaredMethod ("method name", parameterTypes)
method.invoke (objectToInvokeOn, params)
```

I am able to invoke the method which is same as String by using the above Java Reflation.

Now I need to change the implementation like :  I need to covert all my function as individual class ( each function as each class ). So i am looking for how to invoke the class name which is same as string. please help on this.

I am trying to implement the same using Strategy pattern as in below :

******************** Step1 *********************// Strategy.java  ( interface )

public interface Strategy {

```
public void executeKeyword();
```

}

******************** Step2 *****************// Add.java

public class Add implements Strategy{

```
public void executeKeyword() 
{

    System.out.println("----Inside the Addition----");
}
```

}

//Sub.java

public class Sub implements Strategy {

```
public void executeKeyword() 
{

    System.out.println("----Inside the substraction----");
}
```

}

// Multi.java

public class Multi implements Strategy{

```
public void executeKeyword() 
{

    System.out.println("----Inside the multiplication----");

}
```

}

******************** Step3 *******************************

public class Context {

```
private Strategy strategy;

public Context(Strategy str)
{
    this.strategy=str;
}

public void processKeyword()
{
    strategy.executeKeyword();{

    }
}
```

}

******************** Step4 ***********

public class Demo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {


    Context ctx=new Context(new Add());
    //Context ctx=new Context(new Sub());
    //Context ctx=new Context(new Multi());

    ctx.processKeyword();

    }

}
```

Is there any option available to pass class names ( Add, Sub, Mulit ) in Context Object dynamically.

Context ctx=new Context(new Add());---> here i am passing Add, next time i should pass Sub, then Multi... How i can achieve this by maintaining single cxt object.

Comment: `Class<?> c = Class.forName("class name");`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I'm afraid your question is not at all clear. You obviously know how to load a class by name, and how to find a method by name. So what's the question? (It may help to have a friend or colleague help with your English. Perfect English is **not** required, but we have to be able to understand the question. This is not meant to be insulting, you write English **much** better than I do any other language.)

Comment: Thanks Marko,, Please check i have updated my question. please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Am able to dynamically pass the class object with below code.

```
String className = "Add";  
        Object xyz = Class.forName(className).newInstance();
        Context ctx=new Context(xyz);
        ctx.processKeyword();
```

In the above code : I am assigning "Add" to String variable i.e to classname (Add is one of my class name) , I can pass any of my class name onto the classname variable, then corresponding class will be invoked. Its working properly with dynamic approach.

But I am not sure , how efficient is this. Can anyone please suggest if this approach is fine.